# CyclicBarrier останавливает свое выполнение на первом объекте

Tags: java

Первый объект срабатывает, а остальные нет. И функция не заканчивает свою работу. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class BarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(3, new BarAction1());
        System.out.println("Запуск потоков.");

        new MyThread3(cb,"A").run();
        new MyThread3(cb,"B").run();
        new MyThread3(cb,"C").run();
    }
}
    //поток исполнения использующий барьер типа CyclicBarrier
    class MyThread3 implements Runnable {
        CyclicBarrier cbar;
        String name;

        MyThread3(CyclicBarrier c, String n) {
            cbar = c;
            name = n;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(name);
            try {
                cbar.await();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    //объект этого класса вызывается по достижении барьера
    class BarAction1 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Барьер достигнут!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Советую почитать чем отличается метод run от метода start в в классе Thread :)

Comment: Я понимаю. Но метод start отсутствует, когда я его пытаюсь добавить. А это пример из книги Шилдта. Невозможно же, что там ошибка.

Comment: Дело в том, что ваш Runnable код выполняется в текущем потоке (Main) и сразу блокируется из-за await(). Если все 3 Runnable передать в new Thread(..).start(), то программа будет работать корректно

Comment: Спасибо. По Вашему совету еще почитал и сделал extends Thread на мой class MyThread3. Все стало работать через start() в main().

Comment: А вы можете дать Ваш комментарий как ответ? Чтобы я мог закрыть этот вопрос. И Вам не минус, и мне хорошо. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, метод `Runnable.run()` выполнится в том же потоке, откуда был вызван.

Пример:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
};
runnable.run();
new Thread(runnable).run();
```

Чтобы выполнить `runnable` код в новом потоке, следует вызвать метод старт:

```
new Thread(runnable).start();
```